# Find all the edges between any two vertex in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I have an algorithm to find the edges of a directed graph from a vertex **u** to any other vertex which has a O(|V|+|E|) time complexity (based on DFS). I have to develop an algorithm to find the edges between any two vertex **u** and **v** in O(|V||E|).

Do you have any suggestions or hints to achieve this?

If I repeat the DFS-Visit for every vertex, only the first time the vertex are white and the following times the call will do nothing.
If I reset the colour before do that, then the algorithm will be O(|V|^2 + |V||E|).

Thanks you so much in advance!

Comment: I suppose "any to vertex" should be "any two vertices"?

Comment: Are you looking for the shortest path? The set of all non-cyclic paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the problem into sub-problems where you can use your algorithm to achieve the required complexity, as follows:

- Use DFS on the structure graph (the underlying undirected graph), and find all the connected components in it. Let them be (V1,E1), (V2,E2), ...., (Vk,Ek)
- For each such component, run your algorithm. It is obvious that there is no bridge between 2 nodes which are in different components.

**The complexity will be:**

**Step 1** is `O(V+E)` - DFS.

**Step 2**:

- We use the algorithm you developed repeated from each node as black
  box on each component, so on component `i` the complexity is `O(V_i^2 + V_i*E_i)`
- Since in each component `i`: `E_i >= V_i -1` (otherwise it was not
  connected, a tree has `|V|-1` edges), `O(ViEi + Vi^2) = O(ViEi)`.
- Thus, the complexity of this step is `O(V1E1 + V2E2 + ... + VkEk)`.
- Note that for each `i` `E_i <= E`, and thus the complexity is not
  worse then:

  ```
  O(V1E + V2E + ... + VkE)  = O(E *(V1+V2+ ... + Vk)) = O(VE)
  ```

Thus, the total complexity is `O(VE)`, as required.